# How create an insert with select in SQL

Tags: sql

Hello i have a question on SQL

I have an insert with many field, but some field must be take update from other table

example

> insert into data (id,value1,value2) values (1,2,3)

Value1 is the same on other table, how can insert id and value2 and copy the value1 from other table ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: you really couldn't find this by googling?? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+create+an+insert+with+select+in+SQL&oq=How+create+an+insert+with+select+in+SQL&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.231j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yes beacause i need copy only one value from other table and not all 3 values

Comment: well then: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+create+an+insert+with+select+in+SQL&oq=How+create+an+insert+with+select+in+SQL&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.231j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=How+create+an+insert+with+select+in+SQL+with+some+static+values. Seriously, it's not hard.

Answer (score 2):

The general syntax of an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is this:

```
INSERT INTO data (id,value1,value2)
SELECT 'first', col2, 'third'
FROM otherTable
```

Comment: no i need to copy only the second value from other table, the first and the third is insert by me

Comment: @nowaySync Then select constants for the first and third columns.

Comment: and if value2 was the max value from a column ? select 'first', max(id), 'third' from table ???

Comment: @nowaySync Yes, what you describe should work AFAIK.